# How can a theory be decidable but incomplete?

Tags: logic, incompleteness, decidability

I can see how a theory can be complete but undecidable.

But I have trouble with the decidable but incomplete.

I saw some examples, but is there a property or how?

Edit: I saw the question marked as duplicate, but I am hoping to learn what property makes theories  both decidable and incomplete rather than examples. The answers there focus more on complete and undecidable

Comment: I just reopened this question. I agree with the OP that the marked duplicate question mostly focused on complete but undecidable theories, rather than incomplete but decidable. And, it wasn't really explained *how* it is that the one example given there is decidable but incomplete. Indeed, the intuition of the OP is: how is it possible for something to still be decidable, when it is already Incomplete? Incompleteness seems to say: there are some things that are true but not provable .... so how can you still decide whether or not it is true? I think the OP is looking for an explanation of that

Comment: Here's the link to the related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3017207/example-of-incomplete-but-decidable-theory-and-of-complete-and-undecidable-the.

Comment: @Bram28 Yes, that sums up my confusion. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*For simplicity, by "theory" I mean "consistent, but not necessarily deductively closed, set of sentences."*

---

There is an easy recipe for whipping up decidable incomplete theories in a given language:

Suppose $\Sigma$ is a finite language (= finitely many function, constant, and relation symbols). Let $T_\Sigma$ be the $\Sigma$-theory consisting of the single sentence $$\forall x,y,z(x=y\vee y=z\vee x=z).$$ The models of $T$ are exactly the $\Sigma$-structures with at most two elements.

- **Decidability**: Since $\Sigma$ is finite, there are (up to isomorphism) only finitely many models of $T$ *(this is a fancy way of saying that up to isomorphism there are only finitely many structures of bounded finite size in a given finite language)*. Fix representatives $\mathcal{M}_i$ ($1\le i\le n$). Each $\mathcal{M}_i$ is finite, and we can computably check whether a sentence is true in a finite structure (this is a good exercise), so to tell whether $T\models\varphi$ we just ask "Is $\varphi$ true in each $\mathcal{M}_i$?"

  - That is: $T$ is decidable since it has finitely many models, each of which has a decidable theory.
- **Incomplete**: $T$ does not decide whether the sentence $$\forall x,y(x=y)$$is true, since (this is a good exercise) $T$ has at least one model of size exactly $1$ and at least one model of size exactly $2$.

> Basically, $T$ is strong enough to limit us to an "easily-checkable" set of possibilities, but still leaves some variety amongst those possibilities. **Knowing all the options doesn't mean there aren't any options.**

The following generalization of the above is a good exercise:

> Suppose $T_1,...,T_n$ are decidable theories in a given language. Then the theory $$S=\{\varphi_1\vee...\vee\varphi_n: \varphi_1\in T_1,...,\varphi_n\in T_n\}$$ is decidable. *(HINT: show the models of $S$ are exactly the structures satisfying some $T_i$.)*

This lets us build incomplete decidable theories from complete decidable theories: simply take as our $T_i$s a bunch of decidable, complete, but mutually inconsistent theories.

---

It is worth noting that there are simple-looking theories which are not in fact decidable. For example, consider the empty theory $E$ in the language of arithmetic. There is [a finitely axiomatizable undecidable theory $Q$ in this language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_arithmetic); letting $\varphi$ be the conjunction of the axioms of $Q$, we have (by the deduction theorem) $$Q\models \theta\quad\iff\quad E\models\varphi\rightarrow\theta.$$ Basically, the set of consequences of the empty theory in a given language is at least as complicated as the set of consequences of any finitely axiomatizable theory in that language. *(See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3387027/28111) for some notes on the behavior of finitely axiomatizable theories which are somewhat relevant to this question.)*

Comment: Thanks! I will have to do more research to fully grasp. Would "this sentence is false" make a theory both undcidable & incomplete, while "this sentence is unprovable" make a theory incomplete(syntatically) but not necessarily undecidable(semantic)?

Comment: @csp2018 No, that's not related. Neither of those sentences is generally expressible in first-order logic. The first [never is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_undefinability_theorem), and the second only is in certain situations - but even when it is expressible, it need not be undecidable (consider PA + "PA is inconsistent," which proves that it proves everything while not actually proving everything :P)